# Python 3: Urllib giving 403 error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I wanted to run a python 3 program that I created a while ago where it retrieves the weather from a website from someone's specific zipcode. It was working perfectly when I tried it a few months ago but now I get a urllib 403 error message.

I got some advice, and someone told me that the website no longer accepts bots.

My entire project looked like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# asks about zipcode
print("What is your (valid) US zipcode?")

# turns zipcode into a string
zipcode = str(input())

# adds zipcode to the URL
my_url = 'https://weather.com/weather/today/l/' + zipcode + ':4:US'

#Opening up connection, grabbing the page.
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grabs the temp
weather_data = page_soup.find("div", {"class":"today_nowcard-temp"})

# prints the temp without the extra code
print(weather_data.text)
```

Then, I was told to insert this before I open the connection:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
```

This doesn't help.

My error is a 403 error. This is the entire message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/natek/Downloads/Test.py", line 14, in <module>
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
  File "C:\Users\natek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\natek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\natek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\natek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\natek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\natek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I'm kind of stumped, and could use some help. Should I choose a new website entirely?

Comment: Can you post the actual code you used for setting the headers? You set the `headers` variable, but we don't see where it is used.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying, this website is not accepting requests that are missing some sort of authentication technique. In a quick request logging I could see this request being made:

```
https://api.weather.com/v3/location/search?apiKey=d522aa97197fd864d36b418f39ebb323&format=json&language=en-US&locationType=locale&query=[SOMETHING I TYPED]
```

If you break down the query string, you can see `apiKey=d522aa97197fd864d36b418f39ebb323`. This means that you need to provide an API key on the request and it will work as intended.

I would pursue the path of checking if the website has a way for you to register and acquire an API key, allowing you to make requests directly, probably based on a set of rules.

I provide below an example of usage with the current provided API key (should be invalidated in a few hours, but I'll give it a shot).

```js
const weatherApi = 'https://api.weather.com/v3/location/search?apiKey=d522aa97197fd864d36b418f39ebb323&format=json&language=en-US&locationType=locale&query='

$('#build').on('click', () => {
  const text = $('#text').val();
  const resultEl = $('#result');
  const uri = `${weatherApi}${encodeURI(text)}`;
  fetch(uri)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => JSON.stringify(r))
    .then(r => resultEl.html(r))
    .catch(e => alert(e));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id='text' type='text'><button id='build'>Search</button>
</div>
<p id='result'></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Would the API at Weather.gov (because weather.com does not have one) work for this project?

Comment: This specific site (weather.com) requires a specific API key, and it is probably produced and provided by them. A key provided by another company should *not* work, but you never know until you give it a try =)

Comment: Yes, I meant redoing the whole project with the weather.gov API

Comment: Oh yeah if they allow you to query by zip code it sure would.